# Finding the element that occurs more often than the other

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, search-algorithms, arrays

I want an algorithm that calculates which element, among two, appears more often than the other in a sorted array. The array will have only two types of elements.

Example : $aaaaaabbb$

Here $a>b$.

I have to find an constant time algorithm. Is it possible? The only thing I could come up with was using stack. Push all $a$'s and pop them with $b$. But it takes $O(n)$ operations. Any better approaches? Need a hint (no solution).

Comment: I feel like its a very basic question, but I am not able to come up with any better ideas :(

Comment: Just a note if your array was not sorted. Go through the array and maintain a counter. For every $a$, increment the counter and for every $b$ decrement it. In the end, you have computed $|a|-|b|$. Its sign tells you the winner. This is basically what you suggested, but without the stack :-) Shaull's answer is good for what you actually ask.

Comment: +1. even better without any extra space. Thanks for the idea :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing that the solution you are meant to give is to check the middle entry in the array.
Below is a spoiler as to why this works. Hover with mouse to see, but I suggest you try to figure it out alone first.

> If the middle number is $a$, then since the array is sorted, $a$ appears more than $b$, and otherwise $b$ does.

However, it is not really true that this is a constant time algorithm, as it assumes you can compute the length of the array in constant time.

This is impossible in a standard TM, and even in a RAM model. It requires at least $O(\log n)$ operations in the latter, where $n$ is the length of the array.

Comment: Figured out as soon as I read the first sentence. It was fun. Wish I had come with up the solution on my own. Thank you !